# ocaml parser "values do not match" error

Tags: parsing, ocaml, ocamlyacc

IHello!

I'm trying to code a lexer and parser for computer algebric system.

When I'm compiling the code with my makefile, I have problems on the value of some functions.

Here is the code of function.ml :

```
  (****************************************
     * Type definitions
     ****************************************)
    type operator = Plus | Minus | Times | Div | Power;;

    type var = string;;                     (* e.g. "x", "y", etc. *)
    type power = var * float;;              (* var, raised_to, e.g. ("x", 3.) -> x^3. *)
    type monomial = float * power list;;    (* coefficient, list of power terms, e.g. (2., [("x", 1.); ("y", 3.)]) -> 2xy^3 *)
    type polynomial = monomial list;;       (* sum of monomials, e.g. [(2., [("x", 2.); ("y", 3.)]); (-1., [])] -> 2x^2y^3 - 1 *)
    type frac = polynomial * polynomial;;   (* numerator, denominator *)
    type exp = frac * frac;;                (* base, exponent *)
    type term = Poly of polynomial
              | Frac of frac
              | Exp of exp;;
    type expr = Leaf of term
              | Node of operator * expr list;;
    type eqn = expr * expr;;

    (****************************************
     * Lexer/Parser definitions
     ****************************************)
    type token = PLUS | MINUS | TIMES | DIV | POWER | LPAREN | RPAREN | EQUALS
               | FLOAT of float
               | VAR of var
               | EOF;;
```

Here is the code of lexer.mll :

```
{
  open Function
}

let numeric  = ['0' - '9']
let letter   = ['a' - 'z' 'A' - 'Z']

rule main = parse
  | [' ' '\t' '\n'] { main lexbuf }  (* skip over whitespace *)

  | "+"     { PLUS }
  | "-"     { MINUS }
  | "*"     { TIMES }
  | "/"     { DIV }
  | "^"     { POWER }
  | "("     { LPAREN }
  | ")"     { RPAREN }
  | "="     { EQUALS }

  | ((numeric*) '.' (numeric+)) as n 
              { FLOAT (float_of_string n) }

  | (numeric+) as n
    { FLOAT (float_of_string n) }

  | (letter numeric*) as n
    { VAR n }

  | eof         { EOF } 

{
 let lexer_main = main;;

 let token_iterator_of_string s =
   let rec lbuf = Lexing.from_string s
   in fun () -> lexer_main lbuf;;

 let token_list_of_string s =
   let rec lbuf = Lexing.from_string s 
   and token_list_aux () =
     let token = lexer_main lbuf in
     if token = EOF then
       []
     else
       token :: token_list_aux ()
  in token_list_aux ();;
}
```

Here is the code of parser.mly :

```
   %{
       open Function
     %}
  %token PLUS MINUS TIMES DIV POWER LPAREN RPAREN EQUALS EOF
  %token <float> FLOAT
  %token <Function.var>   VAR
  %start yacc_eqn
  %start yacc_expr
  %type <Function.eqn>  yacc_eqn
  %type <Function.expr> yacc_expr

  %%
  yacc_eqn:
     exp EQUALS exp EOF   { ($1, $3) }

  yacc_expr:
     exp EOF              { $1 }

  exp:
     op1                  { $1 }

  op1:
     op2                  { $1 }
   | op1 PLUS op2         { Node(Plus, [$1; $3]) }
   | op1 MINUS op2        { Node(Minus, [$1; $3]) }

  op2:
     op3                  { $1 }
   | op2 TIMES op3        { Node(Times, [$1; $3]) }
   | op2 DIV op3          { Node(Div, [$1; $3]) }

  op3:
     op4                  { $1 }
   | op3 op4              { Node(Times, [$1; $2]) }

  op4:
     leaf                 { $1 }
   | op4 POWER leaf       { Node(Power, [$1; $3]) }

  leaf:
     atom                 { $1 }
   | LPAREN exp RPAREN    { $2 }

  atom:
     VAR                  { Leaf(Poly(poly_of_var $1)) }
   | FLOAT                { Leaf(Poly(poly_of_float $1)) }

  %%

  let eqn_of_string s  = yacc_eqn  Lexer.lexer_main (Lexing.from_string s);;
  let expr_of_string s = yacc_expr Lexer.lexer_main (Lexing.from_string s);;

  let parse_eqn  = eqn_of_string;; 
  let parse_expr = expr_of_string;;
```

The problem is that in the parser.mli which is create with the makefile, the value of yacc_eqn and yacc_expr are :

```
    val yacc_eqn :
      (Lexing.lexbuf  -> token) -> Lexing.lexbuf -> Function.eqn
    val yacc_expr :
      (Lexing.lexbuf  -> token) -> Lexing.lexbuf -> Function.expr
```

And I have the following error :

```
The implementation parser.ml does not match the interface parser.cmi:
   Values do not match:
     val yacc_eqn :
       (Lexing.lexbuf -> Function.token) -> Lexing.lexbuf -> Function.eqn
   is not included in
     val yacc_eqn :
       (Lexing.lexbuf -> token) -> Lexing.lexbuf -> Function.eqn
```

I think the solution might be to something like a cast, but I have stricly no idea how to do that ... Anyone help ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: There is no need to define `token` in function.ml. Try to simply remove it.

Comment: hello ! thanks. I remove token from function.ml
Unfortenately, after fix some compilation errors, the problem is the same.
The expression type is Lexing.lexbuf -> Parser.token but an expression was expected of type Lexing.lexbuf -> token . Do you have any idea ?

Comment: I think I might have a solution. I move the last four line of my parler.mly into my main.ml. Like this, there is no compilation error. Do you think this solution is viable ?

Comment: Frankly speaking it's a bit strange. And if, instead of moving those lines from `parser.mly` to `main.ml`, you move it after line `open Function
` in `parser.mly` does it still insulting you with this error message?

Comment: Hold on, no, of course those lines doesn't belong to parser, so, yes, you need to move them (don't know where, tho).

Comment: @vonaka To answer your first message, yes it still insulting me when I move thoses lines after `open Function` . I think `main.ml` is the right place, but I'll see if my thought is right when the project will be more consequent. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help !